# Printing correctly posts - small margins

Tags: bug, printing

When I try to print the Stack Exchange webpages, the margins are too small:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=14184950736491452307

[image]

Is there a way to print it correctly?

Comment: Could you perhaps save that as an actual image instead of a PDF on some sketchy third-party download service? Then you can just upload the image using our built-in tool.